# Why is \thepage set to \relax in a \protected@write?

Tags: latex-base

In the kernel the definition of `protected@write` includes the setting of the `\thepage` to
 `\relax`. Why is this and are there other means to ensure that `thepage` is not expanded?

```
\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
     \begingroup
     \let\thepage\relax
     #2%
     \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
     \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
     \reserved@a
     \endgroup
     \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nice trick isn't it:-)

the `\write` doesn't happen until the page is shipped out in the output routine (it is not `\immediate`) so you want to `\edef` most macros so that they expand at this point while you know they are defined, otherwise the local environment might end, all the macros that are in the argument become undefined and you get undefined command errors during the `\shipout`. But the main reason for using a delayed write at all is so that page numbers fro cross references and the like get written out with the correct number which is only known at `\shipout` so you don't want that to expand early. So first do an `\edef` with `\thepage` set to `\relax` so it doesn't expand, then `\write` the result of that so `\thepage`  can expand later in the output routine.

Comment: Nice trick indeed. There is also a nice follow-up trick by Kastrup in the `perpage` package where it imitates its behaviour for a  custom counter -- takes a free ride into shipout:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides yes the `#2` in the definition you show is just a hook to allow other commands to get similar local definitions.

Answer (score 11):

If it were expanded during `\edef\reserved@a`, it could have the *wrong* page number. Instead it is passed unexpanded inside `\write`, which will be executed during the next shipout operation, where it will expand to the correct value. At that time the redefinition to `\relax` will have been forgotten.

When a control sequence is equivalent to `\relax` it's left unchanged in an `\edef` operation (the same holds for any unexpandable token).

Comment: There would be other ways to avoid this (appropriate `\noexpand`, use of a toks, ...): I wonder if this particular approach saves a few tokens.

Comment: @JosephWright It's not clear where you would put `\noexpand` or toks register use since you don't know where or if `\thepage` appears and you want to (protected0) expand everything else but thepage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was thinking you'd set this up in the third argument to `\protected@write`, as you already do for other material to be protected from expansion (e.g. `\string\newlabel`). Untested, of course, and there are no comments in the code :-)

Comment: @JosephWright One should remember to put `\let\thepage\relax` in the second argument every time `\protected@write` is used, if it were not part of the definition.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's in a way my point: `\thepage` is expandable, `\protected@write` is an `\edef`-like command so with my 'LaTeX3 hat' on I would not support the approach here for LaTeX3. However, I can see a token-saving argument in 1994 for this plan for LaTeX2e.

Comment: @JosephWright If there weren't problems with "fragile" tokens, the `\protected@edef` wouldn't be needed and just a `\write` could be performed, so no trick with `\thepage` needing to survive `\protected@edef` unchanged.

Comment: no you'd want an `\edef` even if it were not for fragile commands (or if we always used etex `\protected` rather than `\protect`) and for the same reason I disagree with @JosephWright that special casing page here is a token saving hack: page is special because `\write` is page based, and you need to edef everything first as the write happens in a different local scope (perhaps) so tokens in the argument become undefined by the time the write happens (of course protected edef doesn't guarantee to fix that but does in many cases)