# Is there a way of defining a command \nullifyifmoved{arg} that will normally act like its argument but act like a no-op if the macro is "moved"?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I'm interested in **a macro `\nullifyifmoved` that takes one argument `arg` and acts like `arg` in normal contexts, except it acts like a no-op wherever it is written to a file**. Some background:

Martin Scharrer writes [in some comment to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/why-use-declaretextfontcommand-vs-just-newcommand#comment97245_47259):

> A *moving argument* is an argument which is written into an auxiliary
>   file (like `.aux`, but also `.toc` and others) which is then read on some
>   other position at the next run. Things like sectioning titles and
>   labels are moving arguments.

This is an excellent explanation of the technical term "moving argument". Recall that macros can be "expanded" or "executed"; `\protect` prevents expansion. I want something converse, that doesn't *prevent* expansion but in fact *deletes* that instance of the macro entirely whenever it is being written to a file (i.e. wherever the argument is "moved").

There are two other questions that are related (but not identical):

- [Macro to be used in a \section command that has no effect in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99473/14996)
- [Is there a way of defining a command which is automatically converted to a no-op after its first execution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99502/14996)

Comment: Have a look  at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98808/why-is-thepage-set-to-relax-in-a-protectedwrite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rather than locally switch the definition of `\nullifyifmoved` in moving contexts you can probably give it a global definition of

```
\def\nullifyifmoved{%
   \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
```

so that in a context where `\protect` is doing anything fancy the command gobbles the following token, otherwise it expands to nothing.

For example, with the following code

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\def\nullifyifmoved{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Hello\nullifyifmoved{\footnote{This is a footnote}}\nullifyifmoved{, goodbye}}

Text.

\end{document}
```

the section heading is `Hello¹, goodbye` in the document body but only `Hello` in the table of contents.

Comment: (David Carlisle and egreg:) Are your answers substantially equivalent? (From your respective solution writeups: Are "a place 'where `\protect` is doing anything fancy'", "a moving context", and "a context where `\protected@write` is used" equivalent?)

Comment: No protected@write is one class of moving argument but there are others, protected@edef for example or  \PackageInfo tabular preamble constructs such as `@{...}` etc.

Comment: To others: **Please see also user egreg's excellent answer.**

Answer (score 13):

All writing operations in LaTeX use the command `\protected@write`; in [Why is \thepage set to \relax in a \protected@write?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98808/why-is-thepage-set-to-relax-in-a-protectedwrite) one can find something about it, in particular the fact that it sets `\thepage` to relax before doing the primitive operation `\write`, in order to avoid untimely expansion. This `\let` operation is performed in a group.

The idea for your problem is just the same: we define `\nullifyifmoved` to `\@gobble` in that group so that its argument is completely ignored; its normal definition will be the same of `\@firstofone`, which simply returns its argument.

Instead of redefining `\protected@write` we can append `\let\nullifyifmoved\@gobble` after `\let\thepage\relax` with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\protected@write}
  {\relax}
  {\relax\let\nullifyifmoved\@gobble}
  {}{\@latex@error{Could not patch \string\protected@write}}
\@ifdefinable{\nullifyifmoved}{\let\nullifyifmoved\@firstofone}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `--verbose` please.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Before downvoting, you should wait for the requested improvements; or you could provide a better answer. It can happen that no time is available for expanding an answer.

Comment: As it _was_, the question deserved a downvote; as it _is_, it deserves an upvote. `:-)`

Comment: @LoverofStructure I never use the "fail" part in that way. Maybe I should; but it's thought for other purposes.

Comment: @egreg Once I know (La)TeX better, I'll understand these things :-) The edit, together with these comments, will serve as a good record / documentation.

Comment: **+1** for an answer closer to my admittedly ambiguous question statement (mea culpa ...). Ultimately I picked David's answer because it's slightly more general.