# Theorems and labels

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, thmtools

Let me give a bit of background before the actual questions. I took a look at `latex.ltx` to see how labels are handled. I found that:

```
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

defines `\label` as essentially writing a `\newlabel` command to the `.aux` file. Let me crack this. `\protected@write` is as follows:

```
\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
```

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98808/why-is-thepage-set-to-relax-in-a-protectedwrite) is an interesting reading on `\let\thepage\relax`, which will probably also justify the grouping. `#2` is empty in `\label` so who cares. The name of `\@unexpandable@protect` is self-explanatory, as `\def\@unexpandable@protect{\noexpand\protect\noexpand}` confirms. Next is `\@auxout`, which is the current `.aux` file, i.e. either `\@mainaux` or `\@partaux` if we are in the middle of an included file. So we understand everything of this `\label`, save for `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack`. [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/8L6CYHm_esc) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8271/latex-sphack-family-of-commands) explain them. Then I see that in an `.aux` file of mine I actually find:

```
\newlabel{thm:defi:SM}{{1.2.1.1}{2}{Spazio Metrico}{defi.1.2.1.1}{}}
```

Why are there 5 arguments in the second brace pairs, when `\label` is defined to only write two such, and how are they used, I wonder. So I try reading `\ref`:

```
\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}}
```

Incidentally, I see `\pageref` which is the same as `\ref` save for having `\@secondoftwo` instead of `\@firstoftwo`. `\@setref` is:

```
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}
```

If the label is undefined, the `\csname r@#1\endcsname` passed to `\@setref` by `\ref` is `\relax`, so in that case we have the output of bold ?? (with some font commands I didn't bother to decipher) and the warning, otherwise we have `#2#1`. `#2` is either `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo` depending on whether `\@setref` is called by `\ref` or `\pageref`. `#3` is the label, and is used only in the warning message. What defines `\csname r@#1\endcsname`? Because the remainder of `\@setref` is `\expandafter#2#1\null`, and `\null` is simply an empty `\hbox`, probably a separation from what follows to avoid unwanted interactions. So we go into `\newlabel`:

```
\def\newlabel{\@newl@bel r}
\@onlypreamble\@newl@bel

\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{%
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
    \relax
    {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
       \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
     \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#2' multiply defined}}%
  \global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}}
```

Assuming the warnings are handled correctly, just like the `\@ifundefined`, this should be emitting a warning if the `r@#1` is already defined and doing nothing if it isn't, and anyway doing that `\@namedef`, which is:

```
\def\@namedef#1{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname}
```

Here is the definition of `\csname r@<label>\endcsname`: it's the `#3`, which was the `#2` of `\newlabel` (or rather, what *seems* to be `#2` of `\newlabel` at user - or rather `.aux` - level), which is `{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}`. So that is what goes into `\csname r@<label>\endcsname`. `\@currentlabel` starts out false and then is modified during the processing of the document, so following its changes is basically impossible. The question, however, still remains: how do I get the 5 brace pairs in the pseudo-`#2` of `\newlabel` and how come I don't see them in the output if we only have `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` rather than `\@firstoffive` or the likes? The answer lies in `hyperref`, which `\let`s `\ref` to:

```
\def\HyPsd@ref#1{\HyPsd@@ref#1*\END}%
\def\HyPsd@@ref#1*#2\END{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    \HyPsd@@@ref{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\HyPsd@@@ref
  \fi
}%
\def\HyPsd@@@ref#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax
    ??%
  \else
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \@car\csname r@#1\endcsname\@nil
  \fi
}
```

Incidentally, it does something similar with `\pageref`. `#2` of `\HyPsd@@ref` is passed as an empty argument, which gives true in the conditional and makes LaTeX execute `\HyPsd@@@ref{#1}`, `#1` being the argument of `\HyPsd@ref` which is what `\ref` is `\let` to. By the way, `\label` is `\let` to `\@gobble` whenever the above `\let` happens, so where does `\csname r@<label>\endcsname` come from? `thmtools` maybe? Well we will get to that later. Assuming that that cs is defined as before, save for it having all 5 of the brace pairs seen in the `\newlabel` way above, we see that if the cs is undefined, ?? is outputted, otherwise the cs is made to be produced and expanded by `\expandafter`s in the appropriate number, and then is passed to [`@car…\@nil`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195581/what-does-car-do), which does the `\@firstoffive` I expected. The alternate `\pageref` probably makes use of `\@cbr`, which is the same as `\@car` only it takes the second argument. So now I know how the arguments are handled in a pdf string, since I see the `\let`s above described happen in `\pdfstringdef`. Theorems are examples of usage of pdf strings, and are what actually interests me, as has probably been between the lines this whole time. I use `thmtools`. So now the question is: what does the `label=` key do exactly?

Summing up, the questions are:

1. What exactly does the `label=` key of the `thmtools` package do? Does it use `\label` internally?
2. What are those 5 brace pairs? They seem to be `{ctr sequence associated with the theorem}{page on which the theorem starts}{theorem name= key}{theorem ctr name.ctr sequence}{empty}`. Is this general? And what is the use of the empty brace pair?
3. How are the extra 3 "parameters" used?

**Update:**
Taking a look at another `.aux`, I noticed something similar with an equation's label. I also saw this at the top:

```
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
```

So at the start of the document, `\newlabel` itself is redefined, making it gobble the extra "parameters". This makes the question even more pressing: what are those parameters for? And it also opens a new question: why is `\newlabel` then re-`\let` to the old meaning `\AtEndDocument`? And under what conditions does that redefinition take place? What is that `\hyper@anchor`? But maybe I'm asking too many questions.

Comment: Yes, `label=` uses `\label`. The `\label` command is modified by `hyperref` to write out more than with the normal setting. I don't think that `thmtools` has something to do with this: it just emits `\label{...}` at some suitable point during its working.

Comment: @egreg but why does `hyperref` want the extra stuff? And does it ever use it in any way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's examine a simple document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{A section title}\label{sec-a}

\begin{theorem}[label=thm-e]
$0\ne1$
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[name=Key theorem,label=thm-key]
$0=0$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\newlabel` entries we find in the `.aux` file are

```
\newlabel{sec-a}{{1}{1}{A section title}{section.1}{}}
\newlabel{thm-e}{{1}{1}{}{theorem.1}{}}
\newlabel{thm-key}{{2}{1}{Key theorem}{theorem.2}{}}
```

If `hyperref` is not used, the entries will be different:

```
\newlabel{sec-a}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{thm-e}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{thm-key}{{2}{1}}
```

So we see that `hyperref` extends the data written out in the `.aux` file. The second argument to `\newlabel` contains five brace pairs:

1. counter's value
2. page number
3. title
4. anchor for hyperlinks with `\ref`
5. empty (reserved for future extensions)

The title field is used for `\nameref`; when you use `name=...` in the optional argument to `\begin{theorem}`, you can also use `\nameref{thm-key}` and the name will be printed, just like for `\nameref{sec-a}`.

Note that `thmtools` doesn't make anything special. With the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{A section title}\label{sec-a}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm-e}
$0\ne1$
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Key theorem]\label{thm-key}
$0=0$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

the annotations in the `.aux` file would be identical:

```
\newlabel{sec-a}{{1}{1}{A section title}{section.1}{}}
\newlabel{thm-e}{{1}{1}{}{theorem.1}{}}
\newlabel{thm-key}{{2}{1}{Key theorem}{theorem.2}{}}
```

The `label=thm-e` key in the optional argument is simply translated into `\label{thm-e}` during processing of `\begin{theorem}`.

---

The code

```
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
```

is a safeguard for the case when an `.aux` file has been written with `hyperref` loaded and then the file is reprocessed without `hyperref`. When the `.aux` file is read at begin document, in this case, the extra argument would confuse LaTeX, so the `\newlabel` command is temporarily redefined to do what it normally does without `hyperref` and the extra arguments are swallowed.

After having read the `.aux` file at begin document, LaTeX reopens the file for writing, so producing a fresh version.

A similar treatment is used for `\contentsline`.

Comment: Just one thing: is there any command using the fourth parameter @egreg?

Comment: @MickG No, as far as I know; Heiko introduced it as a hook for future extensions.